# Cannot initiate Cloud shell in conceirge directory in Azure (during learning)

Tags: azure

I get the following error when trying to open the cloud shell on the sandbox.
I have already cleared the cache from chrome and also did fresh login.

What could be the reason? How do I solve this?
(I have checked other articles, but the message is different. I also tried a few things like checking the provider, and making sure I am using the correct directory)

```
Storage creation failed
Error: 403
{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'live.com#<myemail>' with object id '91194b67-eaf4-****-****-c708e698****' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/0fb9d448-****-481e-8955-fe9e8c2d****/resourcegroups/cloud-shell-storage-centralindia' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}
Can't create a storage account. Please try again.
```

Comment: Did you also close all browsers, and restart your machine?